# Insert different menu items into one menu template

Tags: javascript, menuitem

I am new to the scripting and use examples from dynamicdrive to make some pop-up menus.
On my perl generated page, I insert many (about 20 - for each svg element) small menus with two levels. I would like to define a template menu only ones (because its structure is the same) and insert menu items later, when mouse will be over an element or click on element.
How can I do this? 
I need your advice, please.

Comment: try http://api.jquery.com/append/, and watch out for ya english! :)

Comment: Nice suggestions. But is it possible to make those changes with: ...onmouseover="menu1(Item1,Item2)"... ???

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul id="insert">
    <li>Kerry King</li>
    <li>Jeff Hanneman</li>
</ul>
<script>
document.getElementById('insert').onmouseover = function(){
    var li = document.createElement('li')
    this.appendChild(li)
    li.innerHTML = 'Tom Araya'
}
</script>
```

There's no royal way, if you want to do it in pure [js](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).
I suggest you to use some js "framework", eg. [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials), it provides you easy-to-use selectors, js templating, deep copy of node, detach of node, etc.

Comment: OK, I am not experienced enough and may be I can't explain exactly what I need.
I have made a mix of the two scripts from different sources:
[link]http://pastebin.com/Adq8RxK3   As you can see "onMouseover="showmenu(event,linkset[0], '', '172.16.50.15')" adds 172.16.50.15 value to the same menu as well as like next one.

I hope I did not break any programming rules by this.
And if anyone wants to suggest a better way or just to say that I am completely wrong, please do it. It is all really new to me.

Thanks.